# MATLAB Eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matlab

So I am trying to get matlab to output the correct eigenvalue/eigenvector of a matrix. The matrix is:
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 \\
-3 & -4 \end{array}

The eigenvalues are:
$\lambda_1 = -1, \lambda_2=-3$

Therefore the eigenvector that I calculated and that wolframalpha verifies is:
\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 1 \\
-1 & -3 \end{array}

However, when I run the following matlab code:

```
A = [0 1; -3 -4;];
[T,lambda] = eig(A)
```

I get the following as the output:

```
T =

    0.7071   -0.3162
   -0.7071    0.9487
```

I understand that the ratios are correct (i.e $\frac{-.3162}{.9487}=-3$) but I want it to output the eigenvector as whole numbers like how I calculated above. Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: @Amzoti tbh, I saw that during my search and I have no idea what that is or what to do with it....

Comment: How about using sym as in: http://fgerid.blogspot.com/2009/11/eigenvector-calculation-with-matlab-vs.html

Comment: @Amzoti yep that worked. It still says -1/3 and 1 rather than -1 and 3 but that's good enough.

Comment: Eigenvectors are not unique and they are likely using different algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

The eigenvalues that Matlab gives you are normalized to have a magnitude of `1` (i.e. they are all stated as unit vectors). You can prove this to yourself like this:

```
A = [0 1; -3 -4;];
[T,lambda] = eig(A);

sqrt(sum(T.^2))
```

which gives a vector of `1`s.

I'm assuming that the eignvectors you are looking for a normalized to have `1` as the value of their first component. You can scale the Matlab eigenvectors into the form you desire by dividing each vector by it's first element, which is vectorized using the `bsxfun` function in Matlab:

```
bsxfun(@rdivide, T, T(1,:))
```

which results in

```
ans =

     1     1
    -1    -3
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Amzoti's answer/comment, using the symbolic toolbox you could use the following to get the desired integral solution:

```
A = sym([0, 1; -3 -4]);
[U,L] = eig(A);

Uint = zeros(size(U));
for i = 1:size(U,2)
   [~, den] = numden(U(:,i));
   mul = 1;
   for j = 1:numel(den)
       mul = lcm(mul, den(j));
   end
   Uint(:,i) = U(:,i) * mul;
end
disp(U)
disp(Uint)
```